# Chrome CSS transform scale display issues

Tags: css, transform

I'm getting some issues trying to use the transform scale CSS property.

Here's my CSS on hover:

```
#pricing-table .pricing-column:not(.labels):hover {
position: relative;
z-index: 50;
-webkit-transform: scale(1.02);
-moz-transform: scale(1.02);
-ms-transform: scale(1.02);
-o-transform: scale(1.02);
transform: scale(1.02);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.3);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.3);
box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.3); }
```

Here's the result, note the weird grey border on some of the list items:
[Screenshot of issue](http://glui.me/?i=fj5zahu1yoxukpl/2014-02-10_at_9.53_AM.png/)

I've had similar issues with chrome and CSS3 transforms before and have never been able to figure out how to solve them. Would appreciate any insight! Thanks

Here's the live demo:
[Demo Link](http://nv-bmc.no-ip.org/pricing.html)

Comment: This is a question about SCSS, not CSS or CSS3. I've edited the tags.

Comment: Edited my post to contain the CSS generated by the SCSS and fixed the tags back to CSS.

Comment: Amazing problem! It appears to be a browser render issue.

Answer (score 1):

U can try to add borders. I checked your code and this worked.

```
#pricing-table .pricing-column:not(.labels) li,
#pricing-table .pricing-column:not(.labels):hover li {
 border: 1px solid #FFF;
}
```

U can use nth child to remove it from first li if that bothers u.

```
#pricing-table .pricing-column:not(.labels):hover li:first-of-type {
border: none;
}
```

Comment: This _kind of_ works. It does ease up the issue however the unwanted lines are still visible [screenshot](http://glui.me/?i=26pnqjq6rcv78fn/2014-02-10_at_10.10_AM.png/)

Comment: Hey, i tryed adding outline of 1px solid #FFF and it removed those little "left overs". On your :nth-child(2) for gray ones apply the gray (#F7F7F7 in your case). I am using latest chrome and it now looks crisp :). Hope it helps.